# How to output time instead of date in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table where startshift and endshift are supposed to output time but they get output as date. All of them are getting output as "1-JUL-22"
How do i display 7:00AM for startshift and 3:00PM for endshift? This is my code:

```js
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
EMPLOYEEID varchar(14) NOT NULL,
ROLEID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
BOOKINGID varchar(4) NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME varchar(30) NOT NULL,
LASTNAME varchar(30) NOT NULL,
DOB date NOT NULL,
GENDER char NOT NULL,
PHONENUM number(8) NOT NULL,
EMAILADDRESS varchar(30),
STARTSHIFT date NOT NULL,
ENDSHIFT date NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEEID PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEEID)
);
```

The insert row codes are:

```js
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('0140581937202L', 'H010R', 4013, 'Eric', 'Luc', TO_DATE('14/05/1981', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'M', 23058194844, 'ericluc1@hotmail.com', TO_DATE('7:00AM', 'HH:MI AM'), TO_DATE('3:00PM', 'HH:MI AM'));

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('0250383009267M', 'D111W', 4015, 'Kneeny', 'Mireles', TO_DATE('25/03/1983', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'M', 2302509213, 'Kneeny.m25@outlook.com ', TO_DATE('7:00AM', 'HH:MI AM'), TO_DATE('3:00PM', 'HH:MI AM'));
```

Can someone tell me how do i output the time? Do i have to change the datatype? I tried using TO_CHAR also

Comment: Well, you have startshift and endshift defined as date, not a timestamp.  I don't think Oracle has an explicit `time` data type.

Comment: @Andrew In Oracle a `DATE` has both date and time components.

Comment: OP is trying to insert `TO_DATE('3:00PM', 'HH:MI AM')` into a date column.  That is going to result in '2022-07-01` (at least today).

Comment: @Andrew - yes, but it will be 3pm on the first day of the current month - so `2022-07-01 15:00:00`. You just often can't see the time part by default - but it's still always there.

Comment: @Andrew That is going to result in `2022-07-01 15:00:00` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=089aefed2a1888a84007ebf9b5c18d46) and if the OP does not care about the date component then that is fine (i.e. they are only going to use it for display purposes and only display the time component). If they want it to use in arithmetic then it could also be fine but an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type could be used instead (but intervals are a bit more of a hassle to format for display purposes).

Comment: Now I'm confused - [another fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5603441cb61d832fd77e9eb6eaa155e)

Comment: @Andrew - you're just seeing the default formatting, which is still DD-MON-RR. You can use `to_char()` or alter your session to set the default. [Updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cf3e857d16aec592105800b8b1c81381)

Comment: @Andrew, You are seeing the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` formatting which is `DD-MON-RR` and is not showing the time component (which is still there but just not being displayed by the client) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7edd7b637c66243ecc4fe020267d8534)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` with the format model for the hours, minutes (and seconds):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS time
FROM   table_name
```

or:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'HH12:MIAM') AS time
FROM   table_name
```

---

So, for your table:

```sql
SELECT EMPLOYEEID,
       ROLEID,
       BOOKINGID,
       FIRSTNAME,
       LASTNAME,
       TO_CHAR(DOB, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS dob,
       GENDER,
       PHONENUM,
       EMAILADDRESS,
       TO_CHAR(STARTSHIFT, 'HH12:MIAM') AS startshift,
       TO_CHAR(ENDSHIFT, 'HH12:MIAM') AS endshift
FROM    employee
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

Don't store phone numbers as numbers. Phone numbers have have a leading 0, you'll lost that. Use VARCHAR2. I had to cut off the area codes to get them to 'fit' in your table as-is.

And yes, use to_char() in your query to JUST get the TIME component of your date values.

```
select to_char(startshift, 'HH24:MI:SS') start_shift_time, to_char(endshift, 'HH24:MI:SS') end_shift_time from employee;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you send me the full code please?

Comment: Sure, the full code, for what, exactly @LovenaUjoodha ?

Comment: I want the startshift and endshift to be displayed along with the other details. If i do select * from employee it doesn't change the time however if i try your code it works but i need the time to be able to display with the whole table.

Comment: Don't use select *, just add the other column names like MT0 shows you. If you want a SELECT * FROM ... create a VIEW and select from that